# Preview broken for one project

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      Text("hello")
    }
}
```

In a new project, this works. In my real project, the crash log says...

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
> empty NSArray' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> abort() called

How do I uncorrupt my project? I have tried Clean Build Folder. Preview says that the app crashes on start although it works in the simulator.

Comment: It's very possible your original view requires some data to be passed to it and you are not passing it in the `Preview`. If you can post the original view we might be able to help.

Comment: Add Objective-C Exceptions breakpoint and run Debug Preview. Preview builds & runs entire application (with some exceptions), so the reason might be in some different place. Without project code it is hard to say were it is.

Comment: @MuhandJumah The code in the question doesn’t work either.

Comment: @Asperi There isn't a debug preview option if the preview doesn't start at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array access in an independent part of the app failed because the preview's simulator lacked photo library assets.

I fixed it with a `guard` clause before the access.

```
guard list.count > 1 else {
            
   return
}
```